# Make WCF request in a loop results in a Timeout Exception

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, rest, timeout

I've two DBs offline and online.

On the system where offline DB exists, I've created a scheduled application that pulls the record from offline db and push them to online db using WCF and Entity Framework.

Application pulls the batch of 10 records at a time and then push them.

Most of the time there are great number of records on offline db that need to put on online db.

So a loop executes that

1. Pulls the db from offline DB.
2. Push them to WCF.
3. WCF calls DAL layer and those records has been inserted in online DB.
4. After the request complete, marks those batch of records that they are uploaded in offline db.

It runs fine couple of times, then it gives the error

> {"Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase.  The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=3977; handshake=7725; [Login] initialization=0; authentication=0; [Post-Login] complete=3019; "}

Why does this happen and how do I resolve this?

Comment: If it is keeping the connection open the entire time than that would be correct.  Maybe close the connection between calls?

Comment: @devlife I believe in EF we dont open and close the connection manually.

Comment: Are these databases on the same network?

Comment: @hugh  No databases are on different network

Comment: SQL server offers two mechanisms to replicate across network, Web Sync (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151763.aspx) and via a VPN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152569.aspx).

Comment: @hugh Thanks hugh for the response but the thing is i need to process the data and apply sme business rules over it before pushing it on the online DB. So i believe replication will not do me any good.

Comment: @hugh My only concern here is "Why this happens and how could i prevent it".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In point 3 you mentioned

> WCF calls DAL layer and those records has been inserted in online DB.

How you are inserting records in your database?

You must dispose your context, so it'll be available for next request that you are about to make.

I'll prefer "using " statement. something like this

```
      using (var context = new YourContext())
       {
           context.methodThatIsUsedToInsertRecords();
       }
```

Try this